# How To Receive JSON Data In Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) with Spring REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, cors

I am trying to **send / Receive** **JSON** data  **from / to**  my Controller Class in my Project.

The **Controller Class** Of My Project Is as Follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dummy/",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public Response getDummyJSON() {

    /*  Method 2: Getting the Dummy JSON Data From file and sending it as an JSON Object  */

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("d:\\JsonStruc.json"));
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
    }   


        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject).build();             

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/insert/dummy/",method= RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public Response setDummyJSON(@RequestBody JSONObject inputjsonObj){

    /*Step 1: Display The JSON data sent by AngularJS */ 
    System.out.println("Data Received:"+ inputjsonObj.toString());
    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory(){
        public List creatArrayContainer() {
            return new LinkedList();
        }

        public Map createObjectContainer() {
            return new LinkedHashMap();
        }

    };

    Map obj = (Map)inputjsonObj;
    Iterator iter = obj.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue());

    }

    /* Step 2: send the next dummy JSON file */
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = null;
    try {

        Object obj1 = parser.parse(new FileReader("d:\\JsonStruc1.json"));
        jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) obj1;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
    }   
    return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject1).build();          
 }
```

The **CORS** class of my Project is as follows :

```
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

 private Properties prop = new Properties();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {


         System.out.println("Inside Cross Origin Resource Sharing Filter Class");
         System.out.println(request.getContentType());
         System.out.println(request.getContentLength());

         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD, PUT");
         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
         response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

         filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

There is *no Problem* regarding sending Dummy JSON data through the URL (*/service/question/dummy/*) But
when I am trying to get The JSON data (*/service/question/insert/dummy/*) and send the next JSON object
through the method *setDummyJSON(....)* then I am having trouble. The AngularJS (Client) side is showing the following **exception message** :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at   **/FetchQuestions/service/question/insert/dummy/**. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

On invoking the URL (*/service/question/insert/dummy/*) from localhost with a JSON String as Content Body the following error message is thrown :

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

What am I doing Wrong ? Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you need an interceptor here, the corsFilter is the only thing needed IMHO. Can you clarify "I am having trouble" like explaining / adding a stacktrace?

Comment: @RC : I have removed the interceptor class from the project and also removed the mapping in the rest-servlet.xml , anyways on calling The URL (/service/question/insert/dummy/) from client side (AngularJS) it is giving CORS exception.

Comment: @RC : Added the Exception Message From Client Side.

Comment: I would try adding `Content-Type` to the list of allowed headers ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers") and make sure `CorsFilter` is mapped correctly in `web.xml`

Comment: @RC. : CorsFilter is mapped correctly in web.xml, How do you add Content-Type to the list of allowed headers ?

Comment: `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type");`

Answer (score 0):

There is **Nothing Wrong** with the above code.

For Some Reason Whenever the **Content-Type** was set to **application/json** in **AngularJS**(Client Side) by using the following command :

`$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`

The Server Side received a **Content-Type** of **null**. Any other Content-Type like **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** or **text/plain** Works but the Problem occurs only with **application/json** (even though AngularJS was sending JSON data to Server Side).

Thus a little change in the Controller class Fixed the Problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert/dummy/",method= RequestMethod.POST")
public Response setDummyJSON(@RequestBody String inputjsonObj){
/* Step1: Receive The Data in Text/Plain Format
   Step2: Conver The String To JSON Object. Do Necessary Processing.
   Step3: Return Dummy JSON Object through the Response. */
  return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject1).build();
}
```